# How do i pass a comma separated list of numbers to my MYSQL as a string

Tags: php, mysql, string, text

great site, ive come across a simple problem (im sure) which i have fixed myself, but i call my fix a bodge, rather than a true solution, so im asking here for a real answer please.

I have the following $sql string to write some simple data into a mysql database in Php:-

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $db_name.$tbl_name (`game_id` ,`user_id` ,`scores`) VALUES (NULL , $session_id, $scores_csv)";
```

$scores_csv contains something like '60,90,45,26,41,80' but the code above will not work?? if i replace the above code with the following, it will work:-

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $db_name.$tbl_name (`game_id` ,`user_id` ,`scores`) VALUES (NULL , $session_id, '60,90,45,26,41,80')";
```

I echoed out the $sql and the string with the comma separated list in does not contain the single quotes in the first code example, but does in the 2nd code example, making it work.

so it seams that although its a string if i dont include the single quotes, there is a database mis match and the data is not stored.

If i wrap single quotes around my $scores_csv variable beforee sending it to MYSQL then it does work, but surely there is a better solution, how do i tell Mysql that my string is a text string, and not a bunch of numbers, im sure its something simple, but ive not come across this before.

Thanks Paul

Comment: You tell Mysql that my string is a text string by enclosing it in quotes, otherwise it sees it as a list of values

Comment: Ah thank you, I knew it would be something really simple, Thanks, thats working as it should now.. Cheers Paul

Comment: I can’t add anything to the answers already given, but the fact you’re storing comma-delimited lists in your table suggests to me that your schema may need visiting as it may not be the best fit for your problem, without knowing more about the application.

Comment: Hi Martin, I could store each number in its own row, and then use a loop, but for my needs, this seams to be the quickest and easiest route and not to mention should be easier on the server load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose `$scores_csv` variable between quotes.

Try this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $db_name.$tbl_name (`game_id` ,`user_id` ,`scores`) VALUES (NULL , $session_id, '$scores_csv')";
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use high-level library for queries, like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and use prepare statement (for data binding):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO ? (`game_id` ,`user_id` ,`scores`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)');
$sth->execute(array($db_name.$tbl_name, $session_id, $scores_csv));
```

In this way you are also saved from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scores_csv = "'".$scores_csv."'";
$sql="INSERT INTO $db_name.$tbl_name (`game_id` ,`user_id` ,`scores`) VALUES (NULL , $session_id, $scores_csv)";
```